rke with docker rootless
I am getting the following error, after rke up
I am using docker rootless
I am also modifying the prefix path, since i am trying to install rke using non-root user
any idea how to resolve this error about timeout for proxy ?
May 11 11:58:22 localhost.localdomain kernel: docker0: port 1(veth9c79bdc) entered blocking state
May 11 11:58:22 localhost.localdomain kernel: docker0: port 1(veth9c79bdc) entered disabled state
May 11 11:58:22 localhost.localdomain kernel: device veth9c79bdc entered promiscuous mode
May 11 11:58:38 localhost.localdomain dockerd-rootless.sh[109292]: time=“2024-05-11T11:58:38.318684072+03:00” level=warning msg=“Failed to allocate and map port 2380-2380: Timed out proxy starting the userland proxy”
May 11 11:58:38 localhost.localdomain kernel: docker0: port 1(veth9c79bdc) entered disabled state
May 11 11:58:38 localhost.localdomain kernel: device veth9c79bdc left promiscuous mode
May 11 11:58:38 localhost.localdomain kernel: docker0: port 1(veth9c79bdc) entered disabled state
May 11 11:58:38 localhost.localdomain dockerd-rootless.sh[109292]: time=“2024-05-11T11:58:38.347542652+03:00” level=error msg=“Handler for POST /v1.41/containers/rke-etcd-port-listener/start returned error: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint rke-etcd-port-listener (0b577d5502dbd934dbc57f00de9eb706d5d0339825b5a6c98ee851d55850a46b): Timed out proxy starting the userland proxy”

I tried creating a docker with port 2379 or 2380
docker run -it -p 2380:2380 ubuntu sleep 1000000

I got the same error
However, if I try with different port like 2381
docker run -it -p 2381:2381 ubuntu bash

It works
Why ?
